# Use time in between in oracle for multiple date

Tags: oracle

```
Select *
from mytable
where paid_time Between to_date('00:00:00','HH24:MI:SS' ) and   to_date('00:59:59','HH24:MI:SS')
and  paid_date Between to_date('1/8/2016','DD/MM/RRRR') and 
to_date('10/8/2016','DD/MM/RRRR');
```

Note :
   1. I need perticular time period only for 10 days

Error :
   1. data is there but returning Zero kindly help to solve this

Comment: Yes, i need particular time period only for all days... in this case i need to use Paid_time  and Paid_date

Comment: What types are the `paid_time` and `paid_date` columns? Oracle uses the `DATE` type to hold a **combined** date and time.

Comment: Presumably `paid_time` is a string? (You don't need to store date and time as separate columns, it makes life much more difficult than it needs to be). As well as the data types it would be helpful to include some sample data, and also your NLS_DATE_FORMAT (as that will decide if you get no data or an error, from implicit conversion).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the full date and time `TO_DATE` otherwise there is conflicting `WHERE` clauses`'DD/MM/RRRR hh24:mi:ss'`.

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE paid_time BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/08/2016 00:00:00', 'DD/MM/RRRR hh24:mi:ss') AND TO_DATE('10/08/2016 00:59:59', 'DD/MM/RRRR hh24:mi:ss');
```

Answer (score 0):

If `paid_time` is a string then your query will only work at all for certain NLS_DATE_FORMAT settings, due to the implicit conversion you are forcing:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'RRRR-MM-DD';

with mytable (paid_date, paid_time) as (
  select date '2016-08-02', '00:01:02' from dual
)
Select *
from mytable
where paid_time Between to_date('00:00:00','HH24:MI:SS' ) and   to_date('00:59:59','HH24:MI:SS')
and  paid_date Between to_date('1/8/2016','DD/MM/RRRR') and 
to_date('10/8/2016','DD/MM/RRRR');

no rows selected

alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD';

-- same query

ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0

alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD/MM/RRRR';

-- same query

ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month
```

... etc.

When you do `to_date('00:00:59','HH24:MI:SS')` the generated date defaults to the first of the current month, so when run today it will get a September date:

```
select to_char(to_date('00:00:59','HH24:MI:SS'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from dual;

TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('00
-------------------
2016-09-01 00:00:59
```

You are then trying to compare your `paid_time` string with that date, which means the string is implicitly converted to a date using your NLS settings, e.g.:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'RRRR-MM-DD';

select to_char(to_date('00:01:02'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from dual;

TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('00
-------------------
2000-01-02 00:00:00
```

So your filter is really looking for rows where the time string, incorrectly converted to a date (exactly which date depends on your actual NLS setting, and many values will error whatever the setting), is in the first minute of the first day of the current month. Which is very unlikely to ever match anything.

If it is a string and is always formatted consistently then you can just compare as a string:

```
with mytable (paid_date, paid_time) as (
  select date '2016-08-02', '00:01:02' from dual
)
Select *
from mytable
where paid_time Between '00:00:00' and '00:59:59'
and  paid_date Between to_date('1/8/2016','DD/MM/RRRR') and
to_date('10/8/2016','DD/MM/RRRR');

PAID_DATE  PAID_TIM
---------- --------
2016-08-02 00:01:02
```

As mentioned in comments Oracle's data datatype includes the time, so storing the date (at midnight, presumably) and the time in separate columns just adds complexity and inefficiency.

Comment: kindly let me know my concept is achievable or not... ? or how to do...

Comment: Which concept - how to do what? The last query in my answer seems to be what you want, if the `paid_time` is stored as a string in a separate column (and the `paid_date` is actually stored as a date, not a string).